# Добавить класс при hover на javascript

Tags: javascript

Господа, столкнулся с такой проблемой как добавление класса при наведении, класс добавляется только первому можно сказать блоку вот код:

```js
let hoverprice = document.querySelector('.category-items__price');
for (let i = 0; i < hoverprice.length; i++) {
  hoverprice[i].onmouseenter = animate;
}

function animate(e) {
  e.classList.add('rotateOutUpLeft');
}
animate();
```

```html
<div class="category-items">
  <div class="category-items__img"></div>
  <div class="category-items__price animated">
    <span 1800 $></span>
  </div>

  <div clas="category-items__body">
    <div class="category-items__title">
      <span class="category-items__title-text"> Райские северные пляжи</span>
      <span class="category-items__title-descr"> Северные пляжи — экскурсия для тех, кто хочет расслабиться, насладиться красивыми видами, теплым морем и ласковым солнцем и почувствовать атмосферу гоанского рая!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="category-items__btn">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="category-items__link"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
//// второй и их много вообщем


<div class="category-items">
  <div class="category-items__img"></div>
  <div class="category-items__price animated">
    <span 1800 $></span>
  </div>

  <div clas="category-items__body">
    <div class="category-items__title">
      <span class="category-items__title-text"> Райские северные пляжи</span>
      <span class="category-items__title-descr"> Северные пляжи — экскурсия для тех, кто хочет расслабиться, насладиться красивыми видами, теплым морем и ласковым солнцем и почувствовать атмосферу гоанского рая!</span>
    </div>
    <div class="category-items__btn">
      <a href="#">
        <div class="category-items__link"></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оговорюсь, код не работает так как нужно подключать кучу библиотек, использую  animate.css , прошу помощи

Comment: `let hoverprice = document.querySelector('.category-items__price');` - надо полагать тут мы получаем первый попавшийся элемент? А что если получим целую кучу таких элементов, а потом в цикле будем наводиться на них?

Comment: получить нужно этот класс, из всех item и навесить класс при наведении, в js  слабо разбираюсь, пробовал querySelectorAll тоже не работает, хочется именно на js решить эту проблему, понять почему не работает

Comment: подключите сюда библиотеки, что мешает?

Comment: окей, щас подключу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hoverPrice.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('mouseover', () =>{
      item.classList.add('active')
    });
    item.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      function remove() {
        item.classList.remove('active')
      }
      setTimeout(remove, 1500)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Круто, работает ! Вопрос закрыт !